# Capture color from picturebox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm attempting to capture the color of the color(s) primarily used in an icon within a picturebox. An example of this effect is how the windows taskbar (windows 7 and onwards) designates the background color of the application's icon square. I'm just not sure how to go about achieving this effect.

Comment: You may try to manipulate the image in picturebox as Bitmap and then use the method GetPixel that return the color of a pixel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get that into a System.Drawing.Bitmap you can loop over all of the pixels and then count them (group by color).  With a lot of colors there could be pixels that are just slightly different that it will count as unique.  Linq can also help group those things.

Here is a rough example of how to do it.  This uses a WinForms PictureBox that already has an image loaded into it.

```
    ' Get a Bitmap from the PictureBox
    Dim bm As Bitmap = PictureBox1.Image
    Dim colorList As New List(Of System.Drawing.Color)

    ' One entry for every pixel (so this could get large with a large image)
    For x As Integer = 0 To bm.Width - 1
        For y As Integer = 0 To bm.Height - 1
            colorList.Add(bm.GetPixel(x, y))
        Next
    Next

    ' Get the groups of colors with the count of each color that exists and sort them in
    ' decending order so you know the first one is the most used color
    Dim groups = colorList.GroupBy(Function(value) value).OrderByDescending(Function(g) g.Count)

    ' You can loop over the groups and get their counts this way grp(0) is a color
    For Each grp In groups
        MsgBox(grp(0).Name & " - " & grp.Count)
    Next
```

I just put them in order, you can pick out the first from the list because you know it will be the most, etc.  The linq syntax is a little hard to read but is very useful.

Comment: Thank you. Now say I want to take the sum of the colors it's captured and then use that color as a back color on another control. How would that be achieved?